# Mysterious Problem! I use `git stash pop`, but run git `stash drop`?

Tags: git

[the terminal running screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7pl1.jpg)

1.I have some changes in Branch_A, and a new Branch_B;
2.In Branch_A, Use `git stash`;
3.checkout to Branch_B, use `git stash pop`; but get `git stash drop` in the picture above;
4.`git stash list` get no stash entry;

Why is there such a strange error in step 3?

Comment: Nothing curious at all, if you know what `git stash pop` does.  By default, pop will apply the stash _and_ then pop it (read: delete it) from the stack of stashes.  In general, `git stash apply` is therefore preferred, because it does not delete the stash, in case you would want to apply it again a second time.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i know this delete it. 
But all my changes are lost after `git stash pop`;
i get no changes in the new Branch

Comment: Yes, and if you read the duplicate link, you will found out why this is the case.

Comment: I wonder why my code changes didn't pop up